# Can I integrate Bugzilla with an existing website and SVN server?

Tags: mysql, apache-2.2, svn, bugzilla

I am running a apache2 server which hosts a website, as well as svn source repository.  Currently, the svn authentication is done with mod_auth_dbd which talks to a MySQL database.  Users can log in to their accounts and modify account details (passwords, etc), and use the same login info for svn.  I was wondering if it is possible to integrate Bugzilla into this system, so that the login and authentication system stays the same.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bugzilla's authentication is modular.  Have a look in `Bugzilla/Auth/Verify`.